# Helvetica Neue Bold Identifier

Tags: uifont

What is the identifier for `Helvetica Neue Bold` to be used in `UIFont`? I know that `@"Helvetica Neue"` is the correct identifier for `Helvetica Neue`, but that is it for `Helvetica Neue Bold`?

This is where such a font identifier would be implemented. If you try an identifier that does not find any reference, it will set the cell font to the default font and font size.

```
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.5];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*HelveticaNeue-Bold* is the identifier.  Here is a snippet of code you can use to list all the available fonts:

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
for (NSString *familyName in familyNames) {
    NSLog(@"%@", familyName);
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    for (NSString *fontName in fontNames) {
        NSLog(@"\t%@", fontName);
    }
}
```

*Edit: Swift 3.0

```
for familyName in UIFont.familyNames {
    for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName) {
        print("\(familyName) \(fontName)")
    }
}
```